# placing a div over a canvas in html5

Tags: css, html, canvas, center

I am trying to place a div element over a canvas (it is for a game) on the center of my page. It is about a startscreen that I want to show over the canvas, before starting the game(this startscreen has options like "Play game", "Settings" etc). The problem is that I cannnot get this done, I have  searched a lot on Google, I have seen a lot of examples, but none of them seems to be working for me. Here is my code:

```
<div id="gamecontainer">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
                Sorry, <strong>CANVAS</strong> is not supported by your browser. Get a more recent one to play my game!
            </canvas>

            <div id="gamestartscreen" class="gamelayer">
                <img src="images/icons/play.png" alt="Play Game" onclick="alert('ceve');"><br>
                <img src="images/icons/settings.png" alt="Settings">
            </div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
#gamecontainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: beige;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.gamelayer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 0;
}


/* Screen for the main menu (Like Play, Settings, etc.) */
#gamestartscreen {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#gamestartscreen img {
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Could someone please tell me where I am  doing it wrong?

Answer (score 23):

The problem was that the canvas layer was in its native static positioning, while the gamestart div was in relative positioning with no positive z-index value. Essentially, you jut have to set the canvas element to `position: absolute` or even `position: relative`, while having a >1 z-index for the startstreen div. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n992V/) should make it all clear.
Cheers!

```css
#gamecontainer {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#gamestartscreen {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="gamecontainer">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600">
    Sorry, <strong>CANVAS</strong> is not supported by your browser. Get a more recent one to play my game!
  </canvas>

  <div id="gamestartscreen" class="gamelayer">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot, but I still have one more problem: I want the element with the class .gamelayer to be centered also. For instance, the <div id='gamestartscreen' class='gamelayer'> to be centered too. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, no problem. You just have to set `left: 50; top: 50%` and then do a bit of calculation on the margin property. Check it here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/n992V/3/)

Comment: When the canvas is over the div then div contents cannot be accessible, what can do with this problem?