# CSS/js z-index(zIndex) drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I have been working on a page that has started to give me some trouble i hope you can help me out with.
My problem is explained rather simple, and i hope that the answer will be the same. :)

I have a CSS drop down menu at the top of my page and right below that i have a js video player. The problem is that the drop down menu is appearing behind the video player and i have no idea why.
I am using boostrap for the dropdown menu and the z-index is set to 1000.
Can anyone tell me why the player is always ontop?

I know there is a zIndex option for js that i am hoping will fix my problem, however i am not afraid to admit i have no js skills what so ever.

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
          box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
```

js:

```
function changeChannel(url, chanid)
  {
  var player = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  if (video != null)
  {
    video.src = url;
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
  else if (player != null)
  {
    player.Close();
    player.Open(url, false);
  }
    if(chanid != 0)
    {
      update(chanid);
    }
    else
    {
      tvclear();
    }

}

function update(channelid) {
  $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data[channelid][0]);

  $('.now').html("<strong>" + data[channelid][0]['title'] + "</strong><br>" + data[channelid][0]['starttime'] + "<br>");


  $('.next').html("<strong>" + data[channelid][1]['title'] + "</strong><br>" + data[channelid][1]['starttime'] + "<br>");
});

}

function tvclear() {
  $('.now').html("No data");
  $('.next').html("No data");
}
```

Thanks for all you thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set a lower z-index to the HTML element that contains your player ?

Comment: Yea i have tried to put a z-index directly on the <object> and i tried to create a <div> with a link to the CSS sheet that had a z-index of -1

Comment: You may want to put your <object> into a **<div class="myDivUnderTheDropDownMenu">**, and in your CSS sheet create a class `.myDivUnderTheDropDownMenu{ z-index:10; }`

Comment: like i said in the above comment i already did that. But that player just wont go into the background :(

Comment: I may be related to [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861485/placing-a-div-over-a-canvas-in-html5) as a problem of positionning. Let us know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I tried changing the "position" but it changed nothing :(

Comment: I saw someone having exactly the opposite problem as he wanted to get the dropdown menu behind the player, take a look at [this page](http://www.ustv.us/iPad.html) to see the differences between your 2 CSS styles. If you z-index the video player (the HTML tag, not the player itself) to 5000 then the dropdown menu (currently z-index 1000) will be behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Imt may be possible that your video player has `z-index:1001` (or practically anything which is greater than 1000). So try giving a real higher `z-index` to dropdown (like `999999`). Just try it out. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

if its flash movie or flash player you might need to set wmode=transparent
http://animation.about.com/od/flashanimationtutorials/ss/flashwmode_4.htm